# Is there any distribution of Ubuntu which can be used to install .rpm packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to install IBM MQ on my Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS). But I some how can't install .deb packages inside IBM MQ [Visit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q129710_.htm) (stuck on step 3). Every time I try to install the .deb packages I get the following [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927813/couldnt-find-any-package-ibmmq-runtime-9-0-5-0-amd64-deb). Is there any distribution of Ubuntu which supports .rpm packages, so that I can download and install IBM MQ with .rpm packages in it.

Comment: The RPM will have dependencies as well. You will have to sort out your dependencies, and **then** install the package. Not look for an alternate format.

Comment: There is a command that converts rpm packets into deb There is a command that converts rpm package into deb https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiX05Lq08naAhWJTJAKHU6ICXMQFgg0MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtoforge.com%2Fconverting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien&usg=AOvVaw0UevXtyd7NRKLEWjAIXh4c

Comment: Have you instead tried the instructions listed in step 4 (the instructions are to use either step 3 or step 4 to install the packages)?

Comment: I have not tried step 4 of the instructions. I don't need to convert rpm to deb. The packages in the setup are .deb by default. It's just that I am having issues installing these .deb packages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no distribution that natively supports RPM as Buntus/debs use different package managers, but you can convert RPM to DEB and try to install from that. The program that will convert the RPM to DEB is called `alien`. However, this is normally not recommended as there are normally deb files as well. Or, try installing from source if you are having issues with the `.deb`.

Here is a link to a site on how to do this: https://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien

Pretty simple once your download `alien`. Just run `alien -k someprogram.noarch.rpm` and it will create a `.deb` file for you. Then you can install the `.deb` with `dpkg -i newlycreateddebfromrpm.deb` There is a lot of information on this if you search this site.

The IBM links shows some heavy dependencies and it looks a little quarky on how the install needs to run. Make sure that is followed properly.